# set seek time in AVQueuePlayer in iphone

Tags: iphone, video, mpmovieplayercontroller, mpmovieplayer, avqueueplayer

I am developing an application in that I want to play two video at the same time, That is not possible using `MPMoviePlayer`. So  I have used `AVQueuePlayer` To play video. As I am success to play video but the problem is in jumping to particular time. For that we have method call `seekToTime` and we need to variable of the `CMTime datatype`.

I am able to jump at time in 1,2,3 seconds etc, My problem that I want to jump at Time 1.2, 1.3 , 1.4 second etc. but I am not able to move the video at that time.

Can any one know the solution of this problem than please help me to solve the problem.

Comment: are you using `seekToTime:` ?

Comment: Yes I am using seekToTime: method . Do you know anything about it or any other solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The seekToTime: method, however, is tuned for performance rather than precision. If you need to move the playhead precisely, instead you use seekToTime:toleranceBefore:toleranceAfter [Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVPlayer_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/AVPlayer/seekToTime:toleranceBefore:toleranceAfter:)

---

**toleranceBefore:** The accuracy of the time **before** to which you would like to move the playback cursor.
 *[time-beforeTolerance]*

**toleranceAfter:** The accuracy of the time **after** to which you would like to move the playback cursor.
 *[time+afterTolerance]*

Lets say both parameters represents the margin of **in**-accuracy.

I have seen other [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3972450/how-to-get-duration-from-avplayer-not-avaudioplayer) on SO using `self.player.currentItem.asset.duration` to get the duration.

Good Luck.

Comment: Hi, I have try this method , but still have the same problem . because may be i am not passing the exact parameter that is needed. Can you please tell me what are the parameter need to pass

Comment: @kunal patel: Kindly see my updated answer, let me know if i can assist further.